# Generate all possible combinations of list using integer elements and their inverse

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out a way to generate all possible combinations of elements within a list given a list full of integers and the inverse of each element.

I have tried to generate all possible permutations of this list and then just make one of the elements its inverse by doing 0 - element, but it is not what I am looking for.

```py
def permutation(a_list):
    #if the list is empty then there are no permutations
    if len(a_list) == 0:
        return 0
        # if there is only 1 element, then only 1 permutation possible
    if len(a_list) == 1:
        ret = []
        ret.append([a_list[0]])
        ret.append([-a_list[0]])
        return ret
    temp_list = []
    # iterate the input list and calculate the permutation
    for i in range (0, len(a_list)):
        if a_list[i].isnumeric():
            val = int(a_list[i])
            # ~n = -n -1
            #val = ~val + 1
            val = 0 - val
            rem_list = a_list[:i] + a_list[i+1:]
        else:
            print("not numeric value")
            break
        # generate all permutations where val is the first element
        for p in permutation(rem_list):
            temp_list.append([val] + list(p))

    return temp_list

#driver
data = list('12345')
for p in permutation(data):
    print(p)
```

For example, given the list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] I would like to return (or simply print) all of the following lists:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, -5], 
[1, 2, 3, -4, 5], [1, 2, 3, -4, -5], 
[1, 2, -3, 4, 5], [1, 2, -3, 4, -5], 
[1, 2, -3, -4, 5], [1, 2, -3, -4, -5], 
[1, -2, 3, 4, 5], [1, -2, 3, 4, -5], 
[1, -2, 3, -4, 5], [1, -2, 3, -4, -5], 
[1, -2, -3, 4, 5], [1, -2, -3, 4, -5], 
[1, -2, -3, -4, 5], [1, -2, -3, -4, -5], 
[-1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [-1, 2, 3, 4, -5], 
[-1, 2, 3, -4, 5], [-1, 2, 3, -4, -5], 
[-1, 2, -3, 4, 5], [-1, 2, -3, 4, -5], 
[-1, 2, -3, -4, 5], [-1, 2, -3, -4, -5], 
[-1, -2, 3, 4, 5], [-1, -2, 3, 4, -5], 
[-1, -2, 3, -4, 5], [-1, -2, 3, -4, -5], 
[-1, -2, -3, 4, 5], [-1, -2, -3, 4, -5], 
[-1, -2, -3, -4, 5], [-1, -2, -3, -4, -5]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a list of the "inverse" and zip to get pairs, and use [itertools product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.product).

```
from itertools import product
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
inverse_lst = [-x for x in lst]
result = list(product(*zip(lst, inverse_lst)))

print(result)
[(1, 2, 3, 4),
 (1, 2, 3, -4),
 (1, 2, -3, 4),
 (1, 2, -3, -4),
 (1, -2, 3, 4),
 (1, -2, 3, -4),
 (1, -2, -3, 4),
 (1, -2, -3, -4),
 (-1, 2, 3, 4),
 (-1, 2, 3, -4),
 (-1, 2, -3, 4),
 (-1, 2, -3, -4),
 (-1, -2, 3, 4),
 (-1, -2, 3, -4),
 (-1, -2, -3, 4),
 (-1, -2, -3, -4)]
```

Comment: can you explain this line ```result = list(product(*zip(lst, inverse_lst)))``` ?

Comment: zip allows you to iterate through two lists at once. when i zip lst with its inverse, i am essentially iterating through the pairs. Then, we use `*` to unpack, it is a way to pass multiple arguments to a function by unpacking a single list-like object into comma separated arguments. That essentially passes 4 arguments to itertools product, which is used to generate all "products" from taking 1 element at a time in each argument/pair.

Answer (score 1):

With [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.product):

```
import itertools

a = [1,2,3,4]
list(itertools.product(*[[x, -x] for x in a]))
```

> ```
> [(1, 2, 3, 4),
>  (1, 2, 3, -4),
>  (1, 2, -3, 4),
>  (1, 2, -3, -4),
>  (1, -2, 3, 4),
>  (1, -2, 3, -4),
>  (1, -2, -3, 4),
>  (1, -2, -3, -4),
>  (-1, 2, 3, 4),
>  (-1, 2, 3, -4),
>  (-1, 2, -3, 4),
>  (-1, 2, -3, -4),
>  (-1, -2, 3, 4),
>  (-1, -2, 3, -4),
>  (-1, -2, -3, 4),
>  (-1, -2, -3, -4)]
> ```